# Only list the average salary if at least five supervisors have that specific pay type code

Tags: sql-server

I have an assignment for class and I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I currently have...

```
SELECT payTypeCode, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(AVG(payAmount) AS MONEY), 1) AS 'average supervisor salary'
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY employee.payTypeCode
    HAVING COUNT(employee.payTypeCode) >= 5
```

But it says it only wants me to list the average salary if at least five supervisors have that specific pay type code. I tried to think of using COUNT in a substring but I seem to be hitting a mental wall. Any thoughts?

Thanks for the help.
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having Clause` with the `Count aggregate` to filter the result

```
SELECT payTypeCode,
       '$'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Cast(Avg(payAmount) AS MONEY), 1) AS 'average supervisor salary'
FROM   employee
WHERE  payTypeCode = 'S'
GROUP  BY employee.payTypeCode
HAVING( Count(supervisors) ) >= 5
```

Comment: Looks great, but I had to make a correction in the code. So the WHERE clause is not necesary.

I curently use...

SELECT payTypeCode, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Cast(AVG(payAmount) AS MONEY), 1) AS 'average supervisor salary'
 FROM employee
 GROUP BY employee.payTypeCode
 HAVING(COUNT(employee.payTypeCode)) >= 5

But it currently only displays the SUM of all payTypeCodes

Comment: @BryanD I don't know the columns so i wrote a generic query. Updated my answer.

Comment: Oh I meant I had to make a correction in my code up in the question details. Sorry for the misunderstanding. It still only shows the AVERAGE payAmount for each payType. I'm completely lost. This is all new to us

Comment: @BryanD which column has supervisor name.

Comment: That is in a different table. Perhaps an INNER JOIN between the employee.id and person.id

Comment: yes that right. get the supervisors name or id then run my code.

Comment: This only asks to display the payTypeCode, and the AVERAGE Pay. I think I might have an Idea, When I comment out the HAVING... The values stay the same as it would be with it in. Am I correct to use HAVING(COUNT(employee.payTypeCode)) >= 5?

Comment: Everything should be working with the code you provided. I tried changing the operator and it functioned as it should. But the teacher provided a screenshot of the result page, its different than what I have. But I think the code is correct

Comment: @BryanD - You can select only the payTypeCode and the Avg even after joining. To avoid these confusions if you add the table schema with some sample data it will be much easier to fix the code.

Comment: We use a script to populate the tables. Unfortunately its to long to paste it all in a comment. I have provided the table creation and two inserts.

CREATE TABLE employee
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  storeNumber INT NOT NULL,
  payTypeCode CHAR(1),
  payAmount NUMERIC(9,2),
  title VARCHAR(15),
  supervisorID INT
  
  CONSTRAINT employeePK PRIMARY KEY ( id, storeNumber )
) 

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (
6434, 1, 'S', 48000, 'Store Manager', NULL
);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (
7255, 1, 'S', 21439, 'Asst Manager', 6434
);

Answer (score 0):

Check out the HAVING clause and COUNT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx